# Option[Elem] in Scala XML

Tags: xml, scala

```
val i = Some(<foo/>)
<bar>{for(o <- i) yield o}</bar>
```

returns the strange value:

```
res3: scala.xml.Elem = <bar>Some(&lt;foo/&gt;)</bar>
```

Obviously not the intended result.
I can get around by writing:

```
<bar>{for(o <- i.toList) yield o}</bar>
```

which returns the intended result:

```
<bar><foor></foo></bar>
```

but why do I need to do this conversion? Is there any trait that I should cast `i` to, instead of converting it to a List ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Option.map` (which is what your for-comprehension uses) returns another `Option`, and there is no implicit conversion from `Option` to `Seq` or similar (the reasons for which are debatable and have been debated). While `Option` has a number of collection-like methods on it, it doesn't actually implement any of the main collection traits so the XML system doesn't know to treat it as a collection of elements.

However, barnesjd is correct that your for-comprehension is not needed, you should be able to just convert the Option to a List or Seq and leave it at that.

```
scala> <bar>{i.toSeq}</bar>
res2: scala.xml.Elem = <bar><foo/></bar>
```

Comment: Well in that case I'll undelete mine since it was constructive. :)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `for(o <- i) yield o` is sort of a no-op... Perhaps this is what you intended?

```
scala> for{ o <- i } yield { <bar>{o}</bar> }
res3: Option[scala.xml.Elem] = Some(<bar><foo/></bar>)
```

Comment: Updated my question to explain what I expect for return.